# Why do i get alter message "Your connection is not private" very often

Tags: google-chrome, security, youtube

what does this error mean and am i supposed to be concerned bout it.
How it can be fixed

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-fix-Your-connection-is-not-private-problem-when-opening-Google-with-Google-Chrome)

Comment: That would cause `Net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID`, not `Net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`.

Answer (score 1):

That error is letting you know that the machine you are connecting to isn't actually `youtube.com`, but rather someone *pretending* to be.

Sometimes this is an indication of a major issue, where an attacker is trying to steal your passwords (for example).  However, commonly it's the result of a well-meaning network configuration, like a guest wireless network that requires you to agree to their terms and conditions before browsing the web.

Google has [a few suggestions](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6098869?hl=en) of things to try:

1. Sign into the captive portal, if there is one.
2. Try opening the page in incognito.  If this works, it's likely a Chrome extension you've installed that's hijacking your connection, and you should disable extensions until you find out which one.
3. Update Windows.
4. Temporarily turn off your anti-virus software.

Comment: Wow, thats scary..I am runing cent os 7.Will try to look into this and find a fix